# Программа, которая будет заходить на сайт и там аутентифицироваться

Tags: аутентификация

Добрый день!
Встала проблема написать такую вещь, которая регистрируется на одном известном сайте.
Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, какими способами это лучше сделать? Что мне почитать? Какие примеры посмотреть?

Из языков, к сожалению, пока знаю только С, С++.

Comment: аутентификация может быть разной. Но скорее всего Вам нужна одна очень известная библиотека. С помощью ее можно все сделать.

Comment: libcurl ???

Comment: определитесь с сайтом. Для некоторый ее хватит, для некоторых лучше использовать готовые решение (OAuth и подобные).

Comment: @KoVadim, dropbox...
Мне нужно всего лишь, чтобы там проходила регистрация с рандомными учетными данными.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Раз это дропбокс. Открываем их сайт и смотрим в [апи](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs). К сожалению, там нет для C/C++ готового, но там используется rest протокол + OAuth2. Быстрый гуглинг подсказывает к примеру [это](https://git.gnome.org/browse/librest/tree/rest).